# Bootstrap Anova and posthoc comparisons for non-normal data

Tags: r, anova, bootstrap, post-hoc, lsmeans

I have a dataset like the following (n=1400):

```
register    country PC1
CMT BD  0.528902409041985
CMT IN  0.659599336404661
CMT LK  0.424746884028921
CMT PK  0.617481735398022
CMT UK  0.432241778651171
CMT US  0.520006978931032
TWT BD  -0.120412754435259
TWT IN  -0.775416939396557
TWT LK  -0.331060813776788
TWT PK  -0.0476004644598422
TWT UK  -0.751168065821314
TWT US  -0.861747850448701
TXM BD  -0.899207300872416
TXM IN  -1.90230790510253
TXM LK  0.257287440181
TXM PK  -1.3102770881823
WBF BD  -0.38312607807368
WBF IN  -1.4048106311512
WBF LK  -0.238559559698407
WBF PK  0.0249239934526432
WBF UK  -0.467017637887557
WBF US  -0.423802534509881
WBS BD  1.53739431443881
WBS IN  0.275786018712733
WBS LK  1.32988601584956
WBS PK  1.68224760320901
WBS UK  1.6017172088108
WBS US  1.34625059689434
```

I am interested in ANOVA and if significant groups comparisons using `emmeans` package in R. `afex::check_homogeneiety` throws unequal variance warning for PC1. The residuals are not normally distributed as per `afex::check_noarmality`. See also qqplot below):
[image: Residuals qq plot]

Which means that I cannot use `anova()` and `emmeans` in one go like this:

```
library(emmeans)
m_dims <- lm(PC1 ~ register*country, data = dims)
m_dims
anova(m_dims)
em_dims <- emmeans(m_dims, pairwise ~ country | register)
```

See the sample output:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: PC1
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
register            4 776.63 194.157 468.6266 < 2.2e-16 ***
country             5  20.55   4.111   9.9222 2.452e-09 ***
register:country   18  33.39   1.855   4.4769 1.411e-09 ***
Residuals        1372 568.43   0.414                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And for `emmeans()$contrasts` (here only first two levels of `register`)

```
register = CMT:
 contrast estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 BD - IN  -0.29759 0.129 1372  -2.312  0.1899
 BD - LK   0.42673 0.129 1372   3.315  0.0121
 BD - PK  -0.05777 0.129 1372  -0.449  0.9977
 BD - UK   0.07512 0.129 1372   0.584  0.9921
 BD - US   0.13296 0.129 1372   1.033  0.9069
 IN - LK   0.72432 0.129 1372   5.626  <.0001
 IN - PK   0.23981 0.129 1372   1.863  0.4257
 IN - UK   0.37271 0.129 1372   2.895  0.0445
 IN - US   0.43055 0.129 1372   3.344  0.0109
 LK - PK  -0.48451 0.129 1372  -3.764  0.0024
 LK - UK  -0.35161 0.129 1372  -2.731  0.0698
 LK - US  -0.29377 0.129 1372  -2.282  0.2021
 PK - UK   0.13290 0.129 1372   1.032  0.9071
 PK - US   0.19073 0.129 1372   1.482  0.6762
 UK - US   0.05783 0.129 1372   0.449  0.9977

register = TWT:
 contrast estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 BD - IN  -0.38951 0.129 1372  -3.026  0.0303
 BD - LK  -0.13149 0.129 1372  -1.021  0.9109
 BD - PK  -0.12868 0.129 1372  -1.000  0.9182
 BD - UK   0.10248 0.129 1372   0.796  0.9682
 BD - US   0.34901 0.129 1372   2.711  0.0737
 IN - LK   0.25802 0.129 1372   2.004  0.3403
 IN - PK   0.26083 0.129 1372   2.026  0.3279
 IN - UK   0.49199 0.129 1372   3.822  0.0019
 IN - US   0.73852 0.129 1372   5.737  <.0001
 LK - PK   0.00281 0.129 1372   0.022  1.0000
 LK - UK   0.23397 0.129 1372   1.817  0.4547
 LK - US   0.48050 0.129 1372   3.733  0.0027
 PK - UK   0.23116 0.129 1372   1.796  0.4689
 PK - US   0.47769 0.129 1372   3.711  0.0029
 UK - US   0.24653 0.129 1372   1.915  0.3932
```

So I decided to use bootstrapping to resample my data, apply `anova()` and `emmeans()` on each sample and calculate the usual statistics for `register, country, register*country`: `p-values, F statistic, degrees of freedom, R-sq` etc. from `anova()` output, and pair wise comparisons of each `country` level `(PK, UK, US, LK, IN, BD)` within each `register` level `(CMT, TWT, TXM, WBF, WBS)`. As per my very limited understanding of bootstrapping, I thought of averaging the resulting distributions to get each statistic, e.g. median `p-value` from all 1000 or more `anova()` outputs from my data samples.
My questions:

1. Am I correct to assume that the `p-value` or any statistic obtained this way is a robust alternative to the one time output of `anova()` (or the subsequent `emmeans()`) as I showed above?
2. If my assumption is not correct, how should I proceed to apply bootstrap in this scenario?
   Before writing this post, I have consulted various blog posts and searched for ready-made solutions/functions in R but could not find anything suitable or convincing. Some references
   [An R script for bootstrap ANOVA and post hoc comparisons.](https://gist.github.com/smancuso/c6a045e3972cd525f4a1) (I changed `lsmeans` to `emmeans` but it outputs same p-value for each post-hoc comparison which I do not understand why, so I left it). [Bootstrap resampling with tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/statistics/bootstrap/) [Bootstrap Anova](https://nadinespy.github.io/posts/2020/04/bootstrapping-function-for-2way-mixed-effects-ANOVA/). [Bootstrap followup contrasts](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/05/bootstraping-follow-up-contrasts-for-within-subject-anovas/) (no ANOVA bootstrapping).

Comment: Before answering the questions about bootstrapping - please reconsider your concerns about normality. The `anova` and `emmeans` might be fine. The critical assumption for this type of test concerns the normality of *residuals*, not the dependent variable. Also, with a large sample size the null of the Shapiro-Wilk test will often be rejected. See discussions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247361/normality-test-before-testing-the-difference-between-two-groups-is-it-necessary) & [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless).

Comment: checked for homogeneity and residual normality, and updated (assumptions are not met).

Comment: I don't see how bootstrapping addresses your non-normality issue when you pipe the results back into anova models, which assume normality. emmeans is only as good as the model you give it. I suggest fitting a robust model such as MASS::rlm() and applying emmeans to that model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `emmeans()` directly with bootstrap results by inputting them into `emmobj()` as posterior samples. Here is a simple example with three independent samples of somewhat unequal size generated from Cauchy distributions.

```r
library(emmeans)

set.seed(08.28)

# Cauchy samples with medians 12, 15, 14 resp.
dat = list(rt(50, 1) + 12,  rt(60, 1) + 15, rt(50, 1) + 14)

boot = replicate (200, sapply(dat, function(x) {
    y = sample(x, length(x), replace = TRUE)
    median(y)
}))

# each column is a set of 3 medians. Need them to be the rows
boot = t(boot)

# frequentist estimates -- won't actually be used
means = apply(boot, 2, mean)
V = cov(boot)

# marginal means
EMM = emmobj(means, V, levels = LETTERS[1:3], post.beta = boot)

summary(EMM)
##  level estimate lower.HPD upper.HPD
##  A         12.1      11.6      12.5
##  B         15.0      14.7      15.3
##  C         13.9      13.7      14.6
## 
## Point estimate displayed: median 
## HPD interval probability: 0.95

summary(pairs(EMM))
##  contrast estimate lower.HPD upper.HPD
##  A - B       -2.96    -3.445     -2.38
##  A - C       -1.92    -2.730     -1.35
##  B - C        1.05     0.369      1.54
## 
## Point estimate displayed: median 
## HPD interval probability: 0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note the medians of the medians do come close to the true values used in the simulation; and of course so do the differences.

Note I used the median as the estimator in the bootstrap. I strongly encourage you to *not* use the mean there, which is a poor estimator when you have heavy tails.